# How can I fix Tomcat not using the new names I've given my servlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans-12

So I decided to rename my servlets by refactoring them but for some reason something in the project isn't changing the references to those servlets and sticking to the old names instead. I could do a workaround but thats not really solving the problem I have with this.

I've renamed one servlet name from LoginPage to Login however if I try to reference it like so.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/Login").forward(request, response);
```

The application will simply say it has no where to go but if I use it's old name.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/LoginPage").forward(request, response);
```

It works like a charm. I've tried to clean and build my project but I just get this error any time I attempt it.

error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 14
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: well unless you can build your project without errors, then i do not understand why you think it would work.  Analyze what is causing your error.

Comment: Fixed the error and same issue. Clean and build doesn't do anything despite it being successful. Just had to go into the project.properties file and change endorsed.classpath= to blank.

Comment: Have you checked that the correct classes are actually deployed to tomcat/webapps ?

Comment: No and I have no idea how to do that nor do I know which classes would be considered correct. I'm a bit lost on what I'm supposed to do here.

Comment: when you deploy to tomcat, the classes will be copied either as a war file or as individual files to below tomcat/webapps - when you undeploy these files should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

So I asked my teacher about this today and it turns out when you refactor a servlet it doesn't automatically change it's name and url pattern within the java servlet. Right after all your package imports you should find a line of code that looks like this in the java servlet.

```
@WebServlet(name = "Login", urlPatterns = {"/Login"})
```

Simply change name and the urlPatterns value to the new name you refactored to and it should work like a charm.